# Jquery problem .click .each

Tags: jquery, each

Hi can you help me with this JQUERY based code?

```
<script>
$(function() {      
    $("#chatIM").each(function() { 
        $(this).click(function() { 
            $.post("chatController.php", { action:"getChat", 
                               user:"<?php echo $loggedInUser->display_username; ?>", 
                               other: $(this).attr("title"), 
                               type: "<?php echo USERTYPE; ?>"}, 
            function(data) { 
                $("#chatUsers").empty(); 
                $(document.createElement("div")).attr({id: 'chatbox'}).html(data).prependTo("body"); 
            }); 
        });
    }); 
});
</script>

<a id="chatIM" title="gowthami">CHAT ME</a>
<a id="chatIM" title="vaisakhi">CHAT ME</a>
```

I am not sure where is the problem but when I press first of those buttons it works but for the second it doesn't work (there will be a lot of A tags with the same ID so the code must work to each one. 
Perhaps its a wrong syntax at .each .click or somewhere else. Can you help me whith that?

Comment: I've tried to format your code a little better, but I may have missed something.  You might want to make sure all your statements are structured and closed properly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It will cause problems if you assign the same id to multiple elements, ids should be unique in a document. You could use classes instead -

```
<a class="chatIM" title="gowthami">CHAT ME</a>
<a class="chatIM" title="vaisakhi">CHAT ME</a>
```

and your jQuery would change to -

```
$(".chatIM").each(function ...
```

Comment: Yes.. totally forgot about this .. how silly of me :) Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't have more than one element on a page with the same ID.  Change the id to a class:

```
<script>
    $(function(){       
    $(".chatIM").each(function(){ 
$(this).click(function(){ 
$.post("chatController.php", {action:"getChat", user:"<?php echo $loggedInUser->display_username; ?>", other: $(this).attr("title"), type: "<?php echo USERTYPE; ?>"}, 
function(data){ 
$("#chatUsers").empty(); 
$(document.createElement("div")).attr({id: 'chatbox'}).html(data).prependTo("body"); }); });
}); 
});
</script>    
               <a class="chatIM" title="gowthami">CHAT ME</a>
               <a class="chatIM" title="vaisakhi">CHAT ME</a>
```

Comment: Yes.. totally forgot about this .. how silly of me :)
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The id field should be unique across the document. Try adding a class attribute like this:

```
<a class="chatIM" title="gowthami">CHAT ME</a>
```

And change the jQuery code to this:

```
$(".chatIM").each(function(){
```

Comment: Yes.. totally forgot about this .. how silly of me :) Thank you.